# Не удаляет данные из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

При нажатии клавиши "Удалить" - ничего не происходит.

```
 <?

    /* Соединяемся с базой данных */
    $hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера, с MySQL
    $username = "root"; // имя пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию "root")
    $password = ""; // пароль пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию пароль отсутствует, этот параметр можно оставить пустым)
    $dbName = "data"; // название базы данных

    /* Таблица MySQL, в которой хранятся данные */
    $table = "test_table";

    /* Создаем соединение */
    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не можу з'єднатися");

    /* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

    /* Если была нажата ссылка удаления, удаляем запись */
    $del = $query = "delete from $table where (id='$del')";
    /* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Заносим в переменную $res всю базу данных */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    /* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    /* Узнаем количество записей в базе данных */
    $row = mysql_num_rows($res);

    /* Выводим данные из таблицы */
    echo ("
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
    <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1251\" />

        <title>Бла</title>

    <style type=\"text/css\">
    <!--
    body { font: 12px Georgia; color: #666666; }
    h3 { font-size: 16px; text-align: center; }
    table { width: 700px; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0px auto; background: #E6E6E6; }
    td { padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
    .buttons { width: auto; border: double 1px #666666; background: #D6D6D6; }
    -->
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <h3>Бла-бла</h3>

    <table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
     <tr style=\"border: solid 1px #000\">
      <td><b>#</b></td>
      <td align=\"center\"><b>Код</b></td>
      <td align=\"center\"><b>ФИО</b></td>
      <td align=\"center\"><b>Товар</b></td>
      <td align=\"center\"><b>Статус</b></td>
      <td align=\"center\"><b>Цена</b></td>
      <td align=\"center\"><b>Delete</b></td>
     </tr>
    ");

    /* Цикл вывода данных из базы конкретных полей */
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row['kod']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row['tovar']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row['state']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>\n";
        /* Генерируем ссылку для удаления поля */
        echo "<td><a name=\"del\" href=\"del_data.php?del=".$row["id"]."\">Удалить</a></td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }

    echo ("</table>\n");

    /* Закрываем соединение */
    mysql_close();

    /* Выводим ссылку возврата */
    echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\"><a href=\"index.html\">вернуться назад</a></div>");

    ?>
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

Где Вы взяли этот код? Лучше удалите всё и поищите другой учебник.

А проблема "неудаления" связана с директивой [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals), которая наконец-то удалена из PHP 5.4.

Строки

```
$del = $query = "delete from $table where (id='$del')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

замените хотя бы на

```
if (isset($_GET["del"])) {
 $query = "DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE `id` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_GET["del"]) . "' LIMIT 1";
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```